# Schedule task to run monthly with current date time

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am using powershell's Register-ScheduledTask module to create a schedule task that runs on first of every month.

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content -Path PathtoXml.xml | Out-String) -TaskName TaskName"
```

The xml has the following content-

```
 <Triggers>
<CalendarTrigger>
  <StartBoundary>2017-12-01T11:00:00</StartBoundary>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  <ScheduleByMonth>
    <DaysOfMonth>
      <Day>1</Day>
    </DaysOfMonth>
    <Months>
      <January />
      <February />
      <March />
      <April />
      <May />
      <June />
      <July />
      <August />
      <September />
      <October />
      <November />
      <December />
    </Months>
  </ScheduleByMonth>
</CalendarTrigger>
```

Problem I am facing is with the StartBoundary. I don't want to supply a fix date to the StartBoundary as the date in the past won't activate the task. Also it's a mandatory argument.

Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You've made an incorrect assumption. `StartBoundary` *can* be a time in the past. The task execution will happen relative to the time set in the `StartBoundary`. In that case, the date is irrelevant. The date can also be a time in the future. The task then won't run until after that date.

To activate your task, you also need to enable it:

```
  <Settings>
    <Enabled>true</enabled>
  </Settings>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is that your XML file has a placeholder date in it that gets out of date and you need it to be updated each time you use the file, one way to do that would be a simple text replacement when you read the contents.  For example, this code will swap the placeholder with a date 5 minutes in the future:

```
$xml = (Get-Content -Path PathtoXml.xml -Raw) -replace `
       "(?<=<StartBoundary>).*(?=</StartBoundary>)", (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5).ToString('s')
```